# Ethernet not detected in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, ethernet, wired

Linux noob here. 
Connecting the ethernet cable shows no change.
When I do **ifconfig -a**

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:c0:26:38:0c  
      inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:8853 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:8853 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:733852 (733.8 KB)  TX bytes:733852 (733.8 KB)

wlp6s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:bb:58:cf:77:c1  
      inet addr:192.168.20.102  Bcast:192.168.20.255      Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::5c8e:98f1:31c3:9616/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:24029 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:22024 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:17760362 (17.7 MB)  TX bytes:3302417 (3.3 MB)
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller     (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT     Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

Sorry for the late update. Here it is:
**sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlp6s0
   version: 01
   serial: 4c:bb:58:cf:77:c1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-34-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.20.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:18 memory:f7800000-f787ffff memory:f7880000-f788ffff
```

Comment: Will you attach the results of `sudo lshw -C network` to your question?

Comment: Ethernet controller is absent, broken, or disabled in BIOS.

Comment: I too suppose that the problem is with the ethernet controller. I'm on dual boot and I'm having similar LAN Controller problems in Win 10 too(it says that it is in 'deep sleep mode'). I have tried disabling and re-enabling my LAN Controller in BIOS too. Is there any way around this?